# How to prevent ggvis from showing html encoding for special characters?

Tags: r, ggvis

I have this a chart with `&` in a variable, I do I prevent ggvis from replacing `&` with its html code on the x-axis label?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
data.frame(x="& label", y=10) %>% 
  ggvis(~x, ~y) %>% 
  layer_bars()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! The regular ampersand won't work but the "full width" version does using C/C++/Java source code unicode format:

```
title <- "\uFF06"
mtcars %>% ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, fill = ~cyl) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  add_legend("fill", title = "Cylinders")  %>%
  add_axis("x",title=title)
```

[image]

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff06/index.htm

Note that the "regular" ampersand character I was talking about that won't work is unicode \u0026

Comment: Thanks, this is a reproducible example but in reality I have a bunch of company names on the x axis that might present this issue, is there any sort of global option I can set?

Comment: @Dambo  All you have to do is replace the ampersand in your code/data  with "\uFF06". Let's say you had a vector of 200 Million company names, each one with a & in it. Just use `gsub` and you can replace all 200 Million ampersands with "\uFF06" in 1 line of code.